# Find a value in HTML Source, and replace value of var with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say this is the code on the webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
SOMEVAR = "SOMEVAL";
SOMEVAR2 = "SOMEVAL2";
SOMEVAR3 = VAL;
SOMEVAR4 = VAL;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://somesource.src/">
</script>
```

Is there a way in JQuery to replace the value of SOMEVAR with my own specified value?

The variables are in a commented section of HTML, so I need to know how to find SOMEVAR, then replace it's value.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is the code you are struggling with, just do

```
window.SOMEVAR = 'newValue';
```

You don't need jQuery for that.

You can also leave out the `window` object name but personally I use it to make things clearer.

Comment: Will that work with commented out parts of JS? Even in a seperate random div.

Comment: My big problem is that the code im trying to replace the val on is nested like a bird in a TON of divs.

Comment: Are you referring to your example where the comments are witin your script tag? If so, it's as simple as that. Or is the html comment outside of the script tags containing them? Then it's not possible as the variable has not been registered yet and is undefined.

You can simply try it out by opening up a console and firing 'window.SOMEVAR'.